# Login yahoo mail using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to login to yahoomail, the webpage is **opening** but unable to write login details(just user name) and click next. Can some one please assist. Thanks.

```
 from selenium import Webdriver
    import time
    driver = Webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&lang=en-US&done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com%2F%3Fguce_referrer%3DaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8%26guce_referrer_sig%3DAQAAAIjjx8Mq4TeRJRK7LQmxwRtYKIC-7xuDmlMz7Ntqkx__noaVScl5QrztmdSvSWeypWPGL-jMG37SKn1WVG_2IQiOSSJ6eEw0m2sQVjeAtI2Yw1V8-wJbN2mM4E7yp81uwlbKWT8g5llvZEkCD7x2jSFrtDTJFYIpi7mYPrCLqmmF')
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(4)
    searchbox = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="login-username"]')
    searchbox.send_keys("gsample")
    seachboxbutton = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="login-signin"]')
    seachboxbutton.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try first clicking on the username input and only after that inserting the username, like this:

```py
from selenium import Webdriver
import time
driver = Webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&lang=en-US&done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com%2F%3Fguce_referrer%3DaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8%26guce_referrer_sig%3DAQAAAIjjx8Mq4TeRJRK7LQmxwRtYKIC-7xuDmlMz7Ntqkx__noaVScl5QrztmdSvSWeypWPGL-jMG37SKn1WVG_2IQiOSSJ6eEw0m2sQVjeAtI2Yw1V8-wJbN2mM4E7yp81uwlbKWT8g5llvZEkCD7x2jSFrtDTJFYIpi7mYPrCLqmmF')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(4)
username = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="login-username"]')
username.click()
time.sleep(0.5)
username.send_keys("gsample")
login_button = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="login-signin"]')
login_button.click()
```